# How to make the start menu find a program based on a custom keyword?

Tags: windows-7, windows, start-menu

I am searching for a way to type a keyword in the start menu *Search programs and files* field and that it will return the application that match the keyword.

An example will better explain this:

Suppose that I want to start the powershell. Currently what I can type in the search field is

```
power
```

and the first item that appear is the 64bits powershell shortcut.

Now suppose that I'd like `ps` to return powershell as the first item of the search list. Currently, typing ps return all files with the .ps extension, along with a control panel options about *recording ste***ps** but not the powershell executable itself.

How can I do that?

Comment: A workaround can be to use a dedicated launcher instead of it. You can find more information at this [related question](http://superuser.com/questions/5439/must-have-launcher-applications).

Comment: Good link @Gnoupi I think a third party solution will be the most efficient

Comment: Oh and please add what Windows version you want this for @Pierre

Comment: @Ivo I re-added the tag Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shortcut somewhere in the Start Menu, name it "ps" and point it to PowerShell.

Keep in mind, though, that this will have separate console settings from the original shortcut.